# PXTimeSpanLong(Format = TimeSpanFormatType.????) not giving correct output/input

Tags: acumatica

Good day 
I am currently using [PXDBTimeSpan] but I am limited to only 24 Hours.
I need is to be able to set an Hour value above 100Hours.
example: 126:11 (HHH:mm ; one hundred and twenty-six hours.)

I have looked into [PXTimeSpanLong()] where i tested:
*Format = TimeSpanFormatType.LongHoursMinutes
*I tried using an inputmask
* tried using just PXTimeSpanLong and setting the Time mode to true.

I looked on the wiki for more info on TimeSpanFormatType but the enum types have not been documented.
Side note: I am using Acumatica ERP to create this field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used PXDBTimeSpanLong with the LongHoursMinutes format. Actually we have fields where the format is selectable via a setup. LongHoursMinutes should work in your case as long as you use PXMaskEdit for your page.

On the INT field for your DAC:

```
[PXDBTimeSpanLong(Format = TimeSpanFormatType.LongHoursMinutes)]
```

Then on the page for your field:

```
<px:PXMaskEdit ID="edMyTimeField" runat="server" DataField="MyTimeField" />
```

Example showing the PXDBTimeSpanLong field on the left and the same value using a simple PXInt unbound field on the right to show the DB value:

[image]

The full dac fields used from the example:

```
#region MyTimeField
public abstract class myTimeField : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<myTimeField> { }

protected Int32? _MyTimeField;

[PXDBTimeSpanLong(Format = TimeSpanFormatType.LongHoursMinutes)]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Int32, "0")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "LongHoursMinutesField")]
public virtual Int32? MyTimeField
{
    get
    {
        return this._MyTimeField;
    }
    set
    {
        this._MyTimeField = value;
    }
}
#endregion
#region MyTimeFieldDB

[PXInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "DB Value")]
public virtual Int32? MyTimeFieldDB
{
    get
    {
        return this._MyTimeField;
    }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 2):

Acumatica pages uses days hours minutes format when bound to a `DateTime` field so you would have to follow that pattern with this data type:

```
    <px:PXMaskEdit ID="edTimeReaction" runat="server" DataField="TimeReaction" 
                   InputMask="### d\ays ## hrs ## mins" EmptyChar="0" Text="0" />
```

On screen it looks like this:
[image]

To get the desired format you would have to choose a different data type like `String` which will accept any text format. You then add the field as a `MaskEdit` field editor control and apply the desired `InputMask`.

Adding MaskEdit control:
[image]

Setting the MaskEdit InputMask properties:
[image]

String data type will allow saving any arbitrary format like 3 digits:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have tried this route. The problem is we want to do calculations with this field on other forms and in Power BI thus using an Int value as a save type would have been ideal.

Comment: My recommendation would be to make the conversion in code or simply use a numeric field of type PXInt.